# Python command line not recognizing modules

Tags: python, shell, pentaho, python-module

I have a Python script, and when I run it in Spyder or others editors/IDEs, it runs perfectly but when I double click it, or try to run by Pentaho Shell step, it don't run because I'm using the pandas module.

ERROR:

```
2017/09/25 16:00:18 - etl_script.py - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : (stderr) Traceback (most recent call last):
2017/09/25 16:00:18 - etl_script.py - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : (stderr) File "C:\Users\giorge.luiz\etl_script.py", line 8, in <module>
2017/09/25 16:00:18 - etl_script.py - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : (stderr) import pandas as pd
2017/09/25 16:00:18 - etl_script.py - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : (stderr) ImportError: No module named pandas
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed? Are you running through a virtual environment?

Comment: probably because it's not the same installation which is activated from the IDE or the explorer;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the IDE you are using ships with a different version or python executable than what you have saved in your PATH environment variable.

To exactly find out if it is so, try creating a script as such:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Try to execute inside the IDE and with double-click and/or Pentaho Shell step and notice if the path are the same or different.

A quick and 'dirty' way to use the script outside the IDE with the same modules you are used to is to add (**under *nix systems**):

```
#!<path-to-executable>
```

at the beginning of your script (must be the first line) and make the script executable ( chmod u+x scriptname.py).

Notes:

- `<path-to-executable>` is the path you get printed with *print(sys.executable)*
- **This method is not portable!** A great way to have portable scripts is to [package it for pypi](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or similar (*when you finish creating it!*) and [specify your dependencies](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html), or use pip to install your packages inside [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/). The latter is what I usually do and recommend.